# $timeout() not calling inappbrowser [Ionic]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using an initial screen(initial.html) and i want it to act as a splashscreen and then call the inappbrowser.

But inappbrowser is not opening. If i place it directly it works.
No error is also coming. The required functionality is to have a splash screen view getting redirected to inappbrowser, user will log in and upon successful login will be redirected to the view.( Individual parts are working, but when i put it inside a TimeOut function it is not working ).

Is there any better way to achieve this functionality.

controller.js

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope,$timeout,$rootScope,LoginService, $ionicPopup, $state,$location,$ionicPopup) {
  $timeout(function(){                    
    LoginService.loginUser().success(function(data) {
        console.log(data); 
        $location.path('app/playlists');
    }).error(function(data) {
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Login failed!',
            template: 'Please check your credentials!'
        });
    });    
}, 3000);
})
```

services.js

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])
.service('LoginService', function($q,$rootScope,$cordovaInAppBrowser,$http,$state,jwtHelper,$location) {
return {
    loginUser: function() {
       var deferred = $q.defer();
       var promise = deferred.promise;
        console.log("Hi Service"); // IT IS REACHING HERE THEN STUCK
        $cordovaInAppBrowser.open(URL, '_self',options).then(function(event){     
    console.log(event);
     // success
  })

  .catch(function(event) {
     console.log(event);
     // error
  });

 $rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstop', function(e, event){
if(userValid){
deferred.resolve(username);  }
else{
deferred.reject('Auth Failed');
}
});

 //promise created outside
 promise.success = function(fn) {
            promise.then(fn);
            return promise;
        }
        promise.error = function(fn) {
            promise.then(null, fn);
            return promise;
        }
        return promise;
    }
});
```

Comment: Honestly I didn't read past `setTimeout`. Try `$timeout` and then come back.

Comment: Are you still facing the problem or is it solved?

Comment: @RaviShankar No $timeout didnt work

Comment: The login service has syntax errors and won't compile. A deferred object is resolved *inside* a $on event handler but is created *outside* the handler. Since a deferred object can only be resolved once, that will cause problems. When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @georgeawg the deferred object is created outside, i didnt paste it correctly, now i have. No Errors. It is compiling successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed and reinstalled the inappbrowser plugin and it worked correctly. I apologize for the confusion